# Error when trying to run javafx through android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, javafx

I'm getting the following error when trying to run javafx through android studio I'm following the youtuve video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6S6km5duBrM when he first runs his app he dooesn't get this error and I do I assume I didn't install javafx correctly or there is something misssing in the gradle file.

```
"D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar=57517:D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\dziv9\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\data\res;C:\Users\dziv9\AndroidStudioProjects\draught\app\build\intermediates\javac\debugUnitTest\classes;C:\Users\dziv9\AndroidStudioProjects\draught\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes;C:\Users\dziv9\AndroidStudioProjects\draught\app\build\intermediates\javac\debugAndroidTest\classes;C:\Users\dziv9\AndroidStudioProjects\draught\app\build\generated\res\resValues\androidTest\debug;C:\Users\dziv9\AndroidStudioProjects\draught\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-integration\1.3\5de0c73fef18917cd85d0ab70bb23818685e4dfd\hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.kxml\kxml2\2.3.0\ccbc77a5fd907ef863c29f3596c6f54ffa4e9442\kxml2-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup\javawriter\2.1.1\67ff45d9ae02e583d0f9b3432a5ebbe05c30c966\javawriter-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\2.0.1\516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0\jsr305-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7425ed91d7dfb083e9bc47e89986d1b2\junit-1.1.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0d24cfe2c796fda9c57df35d8a74123a\espresso-core-3.1.1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a608165d95f86143cba4c8341adafa7\runner-1.1.1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2a44d956c8871880668bd394d398fe0c\core-1.1.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2a44d956c8871880668bd394d398fe0c\core-1.1.0\res;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\458208e37f3f1eebc2250c8f8e9b3875\monitor-1.1.1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\33f2ad6caddf6fba1f77f63d4fe5ad8b\espresso-idling-resource-3.1.1\jars\classes.jar;D:\Program Files\dalvik-sdk-8.60.12\dalvik-sdk\rt\lib\ext\compat-1.0.0.jar;D:\Program Files\dalvik-sdk-8.60.12\dalvik-sdk\rt\lib\ext\jfxdvk.jar;D:\Program Files\dalvik-sdk-8.60.12\dalvik-sdk\rt\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.collection\collection\1.0.0\42858b26cafdaa69b6149f45dfc2894007bc2c7a\collection-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common\2.0.0\e070ffae07452331bc5684734fce6831d531785c\lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.arch.core\core-common\2.0.0\bb21b9a11761451b51624ac428d1f1bb5deeac38\core-common-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation\1.0.0\45599f2cd5965ac05a1488fa2a5c0cdd7c499ead\annotation-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.constraintlayout\constraintlayout-solver\1.1.3\54abe9ffb22cc9019b0b6fcc10f185cc4e67b34e\constraintlayout-solver-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\dc02e4ad9e87f4e264660b5b5bba3a17\appcompat-1.0.2\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\dc02e4ad9e87f4e264660b5b5bba3a17\appcompat-1.0.2\res;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4605a21e12a8645bef4b83cb2b88a912\fragment-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\8a1c9941cb691a0f9238667659c29600\vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1b0ff979c29818162f2b7945e5e1e96d\legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\dd75fe0a92960c0bcab06b06ab2a651a\legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1155bf6e871a8ef3d082fe4d7bc1c4cf\vectordrawable-1.0.1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ae065302592ba49f9fb4928340d8efa9\loader-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\490b544968be08fcd1fcc3f5063a0f7b\viewpager-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1b599049f194fedaaf6f4b938cd8d985\coordinatorlayout-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1b599049f194fedaaf6f4b938cd8d985\coordinatorlayout-1.0.0\res;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\31e47c9007cfb1dc19ac5b6ccd4993de\drawerlayout-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cbef76832362a38dc8d09daf55cd014c\slidingpanelayout-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0666e99522dc8eb404fd705c0a30268e\customview-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1a74df119be238f0b688e699d8816de6\swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ab2664472f85163e9edf93101b64420a\asynclayoutinflater-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bb9840bbc16ebcd703e1098d1392debd\core-1.0.1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bb9840bbc16ebcd703e1098d1392debd\core-1.0.1\res;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\da75cc2faac1d9a7874b0b98a13cb764\versionedparcelable-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\eacbe5e6d34452344629aa94e46b7609\cursoradapter-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a3b877b6205ecc047be01c3eff9a3856\lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cbe918004125903a7f9d3116426c25a3\documentfile-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1bf081f08caf8d223b1dd0b46532ed06\localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c9f0013b8e35da8c52cd97e749ff5cfa\print-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4ac9670d15fb10bda09f9a7d50f548ad\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5545716faecce53213444cdb59275790\lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\44ebdf80a8e0e34fb0252e408c7be782\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2017a51c315e7b54e0ffbb188f94980b\core-runtime-2.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c8047a614429aa088a935d74f852de36\interpolator-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2f5b08274a3d2356200270969b95cdc3\constraintlayout-1.1.3\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\dziv9\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2f5b08274a3d2356200270969b95cdc3\constraintlayout-1.1.3\res" checkers.CheckersApps
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:223)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:198)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:210)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

Whoopsy that wasnt very smart of me here are the gradle files
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.draught"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        additionalParameters=['--core-library']
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir file("D:\\Program Files\\dalvik-sdk-8.60.12\\dalvik-sdk\\rt\\lib")
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'D:\\Program Files\\dalvik-sdk-8.60.12\\dalvik-sdk\\rt\\lib\\ext')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'C:\\Users\\dziv9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-jmods\\javafx-jmods-11.0.2')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: That is not android studio. its IntelliJ IDEA. you can download it here https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Asking if something is missing in the Gradle file and not posting it is pretty funny. How can anybody tell u then? 

Comment: Whoopsy that wasn't very smart of me here is the gradle files